# In Azure NGINX server is running but website is not loading

Tags: azure, nginx

I have been having trouble connecting to my virtual machines in Azure since yesterday. So to test I created a new marketplace ubuntu 18.04 image VM and installed nginx, without changing anything.

I expected that navigating to the ip would give me the default nginx website as it usually does but instead it just times out and declares it inaccessible. Nginx is running fine according to systemctl and ufw is disabled as it comes by default in azure images.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: If you created a new VM using the Azure Portal, your VM is probably behind a Network Security Group. Check the networking tab of the VM

Comment: It looks to be set up as default which looks to be appropriate. [https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq_PS91Q8SeIwVOflNkhzH0MJBDs?e=ev7zsA] Networking values are also default and allowing internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in your screenshot, Port 80 is not open in your Network Security Group. This is why you are not seeing NGINX.

"DenyAllInBound" will deny all inbound traffic which has not been explicitly allowed by other rules with higher priority.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic

Comment: indeed I added the port 80 outbound rule and it worked. I am quite certain I did not have to configure that by hand before, but I'll keep it in mind. Thank you!